# Mod ReWrite Catch-All Subdomain

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, .htaccess

Basically I want `*.domain.com` to pull up `domain.com/*/` (not redirect).

I went into the subdomains section of cPanel and set a wildcard for this domain. It appears to be resolving correctly, ie *.domain.com is bringing up domain.com.

I've now made a htaccess file in the public_html directory containing:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options +Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !www.domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?([a-z0-9-]+).domain.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) %2/$1 [L]
```

The error I'm getting is '500 Internal Server Error', any ideas?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/586129/create-subdomains-on-the-fly-with-htaccess-php

Comment: Hmm, doesn't really help me unless I know that adding a wildcard in cPanel does all that stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer to this StackOverflow question: "[Create Subdomains on the Fly With .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/586129/create-subdomains-on-the-fly-with-htaccess-php)"

See answers on the question, specifically [this link](http://www.webmasterworld.com/apache/3163397.htm) which has examples which should work in your situation.

There are a couple of issues that the Webmasterworld post addresses, including subdomain recursion since the .htaccess also impacts your subdirectories in your main www root.

The final code is like so:

```
RewriteBase /

#### URL Rewrite Handler for Subdomains (by Randall Krause) ####

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_SUBDOMAIN} ="" 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z0-9][-a-z0-9]+)\.mydomain\.org\.?(:80)?$ [NC] 
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/subdomains/%1 -d 
RewriteRule ^(.*) subdomains/%1/$1 [E=SUBDOMAIN:%1,L] 
RewriteRule ^ - [E=SUBDOMAIN:%{ENV:REDIRECT_SUBDOMAIN},L]
```

If you want to see what your above code errors out on (what is creating the 500 error), check your error_log. My guess is that it is causing recursion.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [mod_vhost_alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_vhost_alias.html).  For example:

```
VirtualDocumentRoot /usr/local/apache/vhosts/%-3+
```

Would map requests as follows:

```
  http://dom1.example.com/      =>  /usr/local/apache/vhosts/dom1/
  http://foo.dom2.example.com/  =>  /usr/local/apache/vhosts/foo.dom2/
  etc...
```

You can of course tailor the way the mapping works.  See the documentation for all the details and more examples.