# Why do two patterns (/.*) and (.*) match different strings?

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, .htaccess, regex

**Shouldn't the two patterns `(/.*)` and `(.*)` match the same string?
My real question is actually: where did the "abc" go?** Something funky seems to be happening inside the mod_rewrite engine...

Given this .htaccess file in `www/dir/`:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (/.*) print_url_args.php?result=$1
```

A request for `http://localhost/dir/abc/123`/ results in:

- result ($1) = "/123/"
- $_REQUEST_URI = "/dir/abc/123/"

If the `/` is removed from the pattern like `RewriteRule (.*) print_url_args.php?result=$1`

The same request for 1http://localhost/dir/abc/123/1 results in:

- result ($1) = "print_url_args.php"
- $_REQUEST_URI = "/dir/abc/123/"

---

**update:** posted rewrite log.

```
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Feb/2011:14:21:51 +0900] [localhost/sid#1333140][rid#23cd4a8/initial] (3) [perdir C:/db/www/dir/] add path info postfix: C:/db/www/dir/abc -> C:/db/www/dir/abc/123/
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Feb/2011:14:21:51 +0900] [localhost/sid#1333140][rid#23cd4a8/initial] (3) [perdir C:/db/www/dir/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/db/www/dir/abc/123/ -> abc/123/
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Feb/2011:14:21:51 +0900] [localhost/sid#1333140][rid#23cd4a8/initial] (3) [perdir C:/db/www/dir/] applying pattern '(/.*)$' to uri 'abc/123/'
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Feb/2011:14:21:51 +0900] [localhost/sid#1333140][rid#23cd4a8/initial] (2) [perdir C:/db/www/dir/] rewrite 'abc/123/' -> 'print_url_args.php?result=/123/'
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Feb/2011:14:21:51 +0900] [localhost/sid#1333140][rid#23cd4a8/initial] (3) split uri=print_url_args.php?result=/123/ -> uri=print_url_args.php, args=result=/123/
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Feb/2011:14:21:51 +0900] [localhost/sid#1333140][rid#23cd4a8/initial] (3) [perdir C:/db/www/dir/] add per-dir prefix: print_url_args.php -> C:/db/www/dir/print_url_args.php
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Feb/2011:14:21:51 +0900] [localhost/sid#1333140][rid#23cd4a8/initial] (2) [perdir C:/db/www/dir/] strip document_root prefix: C:/db/www/dir/print_url_args.php -> /dir/print_url_args.php
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Feb/2011:14:21:51 +0900] [localhost/sid#1333140][rid#23cd4a8/initial] (1) [perdir C:/db/www/dir/] internal redirect with /dir/print_url_args.php [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Feb/2011:14:21:51 +0900] [localhost/sid#1333140][rid#43833c8/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir C:/db/www/dir/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/db/www/dir/print_url_args.php -> print_url_args.php
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Feb/2011:14:21:51 +0900] [localhost/sid#1333140][rid#43833c8/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir C:/db/www/dir/] applying pattern '(/.*)$' to uri 'print_url_args.php'
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Feb/2011:14:21:51 +0900] [localhost/sid#1333140][rid#43833c8/initial/redir#1] (1) [perdir C:/db/www/dir/] pass through C:/db/www/dir/print_url_args.php
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Feb/2011:14:24:54 +0900] [localhost/sid#1333140][rid#23bf470/initial] (3) [perdir C:/db/www/dir/] add path info postfix: C:/db/www/dir/abc -> C:/db/www/dir/abc/123/
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Feb/2011:14:24:54 +0900] [localhost/sid#1333140][rid#23bf470/initial] (3) [perdir C:/db/www/dir/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/db/www/dir/abc/123/ -> abc/123/
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Feb/2011:14:24:54 +0900] [localhost/sid#1333140][rid#23bf470/initial] (3) [perdir C:/db/www/dir/] applying pattern '(.*)$' to uri 'abc/123/'
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Feb/2011:14:24:54 +0900] [localhost/sid#1333140][rid#23bf470/initial] (2) [perdir C:/db/www/dir/] rewrite 'abc/123/' -> 'print_url_args.php?result=abc/123/'
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Feb/2011:14:24:54 +0900] [localhost/sid#1333140][rid#23bf470/initial] (3) split uri=print_url_args.php?result=abc/123/ -> uri=print_url_args.php, args=result=abc/123/
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Feb/2011:14:24:54 +0900] [localhost/sid#1333140][rid#23bf470/initial] (3) [perdir C:/db/www/dir/] add per-dir prefix: print_url_args.php -> C:/db/www/dir/print_url_args.php
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Feb/2011:14:24:54 +0900] [localhost/sid#1333140][rid#23bf470/initial] (2) [perdir C:/db/www/dir/] strip document_root prefix: C:/db/www/dir/print_url_args.php -> /dir/print_url_args.php
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Feb/2011:14:24:54 +0900] [localhost/sid#1333140][rid#23bf470/initial] (1) [perdir C:/db/www/dir/] internal redirect with /dir/print_url_args.php [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Feb/2011:14:24:54 +0900] [localhost/sid#1333140][rid#23fda10/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir C:/db/www/dir/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/db/www/dir/print_url_args.php -> print_url_args.php
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Feb/2011:14:24:54 +0900] [localhost/sid#1333140][rid#23fda10/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir C:/db/www/dir/] applying pattern '(.*)$' to uri 'print_url_args.php'
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Feb/2011:14:24:54 +0900] [localhost/sid#1333140][rid#23fda10/initial/redir#1] (2) [perdir C:/db/www/dir/] rewrite 'print_url_args.php' -> 'print_url_args.php?result=print_url_args.php'
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Feb/2011:14:24:54 +0900] [localhost/sid#1333140][rid#23fda10/initial/redir#1] (3) split uri=print_url_args.php?result=print_url_args.php -> uri=print_url_args.php, args=result=print_url_args.php
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Feb/2011:14:24:54 +0900] [localhost/sid#1333140][rid#23fda10/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir C:/db/www/dir/] add per-dir prefix: print_url_args.php -> C:/db/www/dir/print_url_args.php
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Feb/2011:14:24:54 +0900] [localhost/sid#1333140][rid#23fda10/initial/redir#1] (1) [perdir C:/db/www/dir/] initial URL equal rewritten URL: C:/db/www/dir/print_url_args.php [IGNORING REWRITE]
```

Comment: Turn on the rewrite log and post its output.

Answer (score 2):

When you are in `.htaccess` context `(/.*)` will never match the full URL, from [the docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule):

> In Directory and htaccess context, the
>   Pattern will initially be matched
>   against the filesystem path, after
>   removing the prefix that lead the
>   server to the current RewriteRule
>   (e.g. "app1/index.html" or
>   "index.html" depending on where the
>   directives are defined).

and

> Per-directory Rewrites
>
> ...
>
> The removed prefix always ends with a slash, meaning the matching
>   occurs against a string which never
>   has a leading slash. Therefore, a
>   Pattern with ^/ never matches in
>   per-directory context.

Answer (score 0):

Your question helped me solve a very similar problem!

I don't have access to rewrite logs in my hosting environment (godaddy), so I was totally perplexed by the "second" rewrite, which your logs clearly explain. From there, it wasn't too hard to understand that the key to making this work is that those recursive rewrites have to be stopped somehow.

There's a great solution to that problem [here](http://www.webmasterworld.com/apache/3163397.htm) (via serverfault user Dave Drager's [answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/28638/mod-rewrite-catch-all-subdomain/28682#28682) to a similar question).

Try this:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{ENV:
REDIRECT_X} =""
RewriteRule (.*) print_url_args.php?result=$1 [E=X:1,L]
```