# Using mod_rewrite as a stand-in for VirtualHosts to host two domains on one GoDaddy hosting account

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, hosting, mod-rewrite, godaddy

I'm trying to do something like VirtualHosts using mod_rewrite on a GoDaddy hosted site. I have a single hosting account and two domains, a.com and b.com. I want requests for b.com/document.html to be served from ~/html/b_site/document.html (where ~/html/ is the DocumentRoot, serving as root for a.com). I found a [reference](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/rewrite/avoid.html#vhosts) to this use case in the mod_rewrite documentation suggesting that it is possible, but I've been unsuccessful. Here's the contents of ~/html/.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
Options FollowSymLinks

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} b\.com$
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ b_site$1
```

The result, when I point my browser at b.com: the location bar changes to b.com/b_site/ and the server responds with 500. The following RewriteRule works without any issues:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ b_site/index.html
```

...which remains the only way I've been able to get anything but a 500 or warnings about redirect loops. The RewriteBase line seems to make no difference.

To find out what was being matched, I wrote a simple PHP script which would accept a query parameter and print it, and I used this RewriteRule:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ b_site/index.php?q=$1
```

The output shows that in this case the RewriteRule matched "b_site/index.php". The RewriteBase documentation does imply that something like that should be happening, but again, the RewriteBase seems to make no difference in the result. Answers posed to [similar questions](https://serverfault.com/questions/28638/mod-rewrite-catch-all-subdomain) all seem to boil down to the same mechanism that I'm trying.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. And no thanks to GoDaddy for making you pay for access to error logs!

This all started to make sense when I saw [someone else's logs](https://serverfault.com/q/235537/92542). It's now clear to me how the recursion is happening and why things are getting rewritten a second time (and infinitely recursing, causing the 500). There's a great solution to the recursion problem [here](http://www.webmasterworld.com/apache/3163397.htm) (via serverfault user Dave Drager's [answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/28638/mod-rewrite-catch-all-subdomain/28682#28682) to a similar question).

I simplified a little and arrived at this solution:

RewriteEngine on
Options FollowSymLinks
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_X} =""
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} b.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ b_site/$1 [E=X:1,L]

Answer (score 0):

Your `.htaccess` context, as well as the `RewriteBase`, are both setting the context for the `RewriteRule` to `/`; this means your substitution would take a request for `http://b.com/dir_a/page.html` and serve it from `http://b.com/b_sitedir_a/page.html` - probably not gonna work.

From the [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule):

> When using the rewrite engine in .htaccess files the per-directory prefix (which always is the same for a specific directory) is automatically removed for the RewriteRule pattern matching and automatically added after any relative (not starting with a slash or protocol name) substitution encounters the end of a rule set.

Try this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^b\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ b_site/$1
```

Comment: Shane, thanks for responding. Adding the slash as you suggest, I still get a 500, but the browser location at least is not rewritten from b.com to b.com/b_site. I guess that indicates mod_rewrite was not finding the b_site$1 directory and was treating it as a URI.